# Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuously part. differentiable and $\partial_1 f=\partial_2 f,\ f(0,0)=0$. Prove that $f(x,y)=f(x+t,y-t)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

We need to show that $f(x,y)=f(x+t,y-t),\ \forall x,y,t\in \mathbb{R}$.

**My approach:** I think the solution has got something to do with defining the new function $g(x,y):= f(x,y)-f(x+t,y-t)$ and showing that $\partial_1 g=\partial_2 g=0$. Thus, $g$ would be a constant function and due to us knowing that $f(0,0)=0$, we might be able to show that $g(x,y)=c=0$. Sadly, I have not been able to successfully execute my strategy.

Could anyone help me? Am I on the right track or is there something much more elegant and beautiful? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry let me edit that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating $g(x,y) = f(x,y)-f(x+t,y-t)$ (for fixed $t$) does not help because one can not use the information that $\partial_1 f=\partial_2 f$. It is better to proceed the other way around:

For fixed $(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2$ define the function $h(t) = f(x+t, y-t)$. Then
$$
 h'(t) = \partial_1 f(x+t, y-t) \cdot 1 + \partial_2 f(x+t, y-t) \cdot (-1) = 0
$$
so that $h$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I haven't come to that idea! Very nice! I will accept the answer in 3 mins (I can't do it earlier).